# Class Instance Implementation

Tags: haskell

Apart from `instance IsPerson (EmployeeRecord a)` the whole code is a part of the post [General Functions with Typeclasses](https://mmhaskell.com/blog/2018/1/1/general-functions-with-typeclasses).

`ghci` compiles the code, but `printPerson` doesn't print anything. I guess it calls itself recursively.

```
Main> :l type-class.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( type-class.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> printPerson $ EmployeeRecord (Student "me" 123) 11
```

Removing of `instance IsPerson (EmployeeRecord a)` leads to the exception

```
Main> printPerson $ EmployeeRecord (Student "me" 123) 11

<interactive>:116:1: error:
    * No instance for (IsPerson (EmployeeRecord Student))
        arising from a use of `printPerson'
    * In the expression:
        printPerson $ EmployeeRecord (Student "me" 123) 11
      In an equation for `it':
          it = printPerson $ EmployeeRecord (Student "me" 123) 11
```

How should `instance IsPerson EmployeeRecord` be implemented solve the issue with `printPerson`?

```
data Student = Student String Int deriving Show

data Teacher = Teacher
  { teacherName:: String
  , teacherAge:: Int
  , teacherDepartment :: String
  , teacherSalary :: Int
  } deriving Show

class IsPerson a where
  personName :: a -> String
  personAge :: a -> Int

instance IsPerson Student where
  personName (Student n _) = n
  personAge (Student _ a) = a

instance IsPerson Teacher where
  personName = teacherName
  personAge  = teacherAge

data (IsPerson a) => EmployeeRecord a = EmployeeRecord
  {
      employe :: a
    , tenure :: Int
  } deriving (Show)


instance IsPerson (EmployeeRecord a) where
  personName a = personName a
  personAge = undefined

printPerson :: (IsPerson a) => a -> IO ()
printPerson p = putStrLn $ personName p
```

Comment: thanks @4castle. It solves the issue, if instance defination is replaced by `instance (IsPerson a) => IsPerson (EmployeeRecord a) where`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `EmployeeRecord` type is like a "box" where the type implementing `IsPerson` is inside. You need to "unbox" the `EmployeeRecord` in order to access the "inner" `personName`.

You can do this unboxing by either pattern matching or using the `employe` function.

```
instance IsPerson (EmployeeRecord a) where
  personName (EmployeeRecord a _) = personName a
  personAge (EmployeeRecord a _) = personAge a
```

```
instance IsPerson (EmployeeRecord a) where
  personName = personName . employe
  personAge = personAge . employe
```

---

By the way, your code makes use of the deprecated `DatatypeContexts` language extension. Rather than put the constraint on `a` in the `EmployeeRecord` type declaration, put the constraint in your `instance` declaration:

```
instance IsPerson a => IsPerson (EmployeeRecord a) where
```